# MySQL Query To Return, Schema_Name, Table_NAme, Count, Size_of_Table, Primary_Key and Auto_Increment_Key

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have another tough MySQL query that I am trying to work out. I need a query that will return the following in a single command:

```
+----------+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+--------------------+
| Database | Table_Name                   | Count     | Size        | Primary-Key    | Auto_Increment_Key |
+----------+------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+--------------------+
| mydb     | account_length               |      2408 | 0.04 Mb     | account_id     | account_id         |
| mydb     | account_log                  |      1225 | 0.09 Mb     | log_id         | NULL               |
```

I am still new to MySQL. I have tried various queries against the information_schema, but have not been able to get one that returns the data I need.

The query would simply get a table's row count, it's size in MB, it's primary-key column and it's auto_increment key column.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will help you:

```
SELECT t.table_schema, 
       t.table_name, 
       Round(( t.data_length + t.index_length ) / 1048576, 2) AS sizemb, 
       c1.column_name                                         AS primarycol, 
       c2.column_name                                         AS 
       autoincrementcol 
FROM   information_schema.tables t 
       LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns c1 
         ON t.table_schema = c1.table_schema 
            AND t.table_name = c1.table_name 
            AND c1.column_key = 'PRI' 
       LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns c2 
         ON t.table_schema = c2.table_schema 
            AND t.table_name = c2.table_name 
            AND c2.extra = 'auto_increment' 
WHERE  t.table_schema = '............'
```

Comment: Great solution as always. ;) It seems to me that you've forgot index_length.

Comment: You're great. I was writing my solution but you're too fast. Congratulations. Unluckily I've finished my daily amount of votes. ;)

Comment: @DrewVS: be aware that for innodb tables rows count is just an estimated value.

Comment: @Pentium10, thanks so much. This is great. Do you mind editing your answer to include row counts? But otherwise this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Nick, good point. I remember reading something about that. Thanks.